# how to know detected node is veritcal or horizontal in ARKit?

Tags: ios, arkit

let configuration = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()
configuration.planeDetection = [.horizontal, .vertical]

how to know the detected plane is horizontal or vertical in their delegate method?

func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didAdd node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An `ARPlaneAnchor` has an `alignment` property which describes:

> The general orientation of the detected plane with respect to gravity.

As such if you want to log the `alignment` you can do something like so:

```
func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didAdd node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor) {

        //1. Check We Have A Valid ARPlaneAnchor
        guard let planeAnchor = anchor as? ARPlaneAnchor else { return }

        //2. Get It's Alignment
        if planeAnchor.alignment == .horizontal{

            print("The ARPlaneAnchor Alignment == Horizontal")

        }else if planeAnchor.alignment == .vertical{

            print("The ARPlaneAnchor Alignment == Vertical")

        }

 }
```

Hope it helps...